# Bot isn't replying to any message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a simple Discord bot, but I haven't been able to get it to respond to any of my messages.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const { GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, 
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, 
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
    ]
});

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

client.on("messageCreate", msg => {
    if(msg.content === "ping") {
        msg.reply("pong");
    }
})

const token = process.env['TOKEN']
client.login(token)
```

The bot is logging into discord, I'm not getting any errors in the console, and I've toggled on all the privileged gateway intents.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Edit

So, my previous answer was wrong, but is most definitely a **better** way to send messages.

There's not anything else that I can see is wrong with the code -- so I guess I'll try to debunk?

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({ intents: [ GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent ]});

client.on("ready", async() => {
  console.log(`${client.user.tag} logged in.`);
});

client.on("messageCreate", async(message) => {
  if(message.content.toLowerCase() === "ping") {
    message.reply({ content: "pong!" }); // or message.reply("pong!");
  }
});

client.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

This should be a runnable instance of your code. What you should do is see if you're even getting the `messageCreate` event at all, by running it like this:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
  console.log(`Received message!`);
});
```

If you **do** get something, then it is unable to correctly parse the message content. Are you ensuring it's the same capitalization wise? Is it spelt correctly?

If you **don't** get something, it's an issue with your Intents, or the way your event is structured.

Try adding parenthesis around your `msg`, though that shouldn't affect anything. Just a thought.

## Incorrect Answer

In `discord.js@13.x.x`, the way to send messages has changed.
Formerly, you could do the following:

```js
message.reply("Hello world!");
```

But now, to make formatting what provided property is what, it goes as follows:

```js
message.reply({
  content: "Hello world!",
});
```

You can also add things such as Embeds by using `embeds: []`, or Components by: `components: []` (which requires Action Rows, not base Components).

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can still use `message.reply("Hello World")`. No problem would come from writing it like that

Comment: Huh, just checked the documentation to confirm. Did not know that! Thanks a lot.